jest tests passing locally but failing in the pipeline (go-server) after changing folder name case
After changing a folder name case and updating all imports, jest tests pass locally but are failing in the pipeline. All I do in the pipeline is
npm i
npm test
npm build
I've added another script into my package.json and tried running it before npm test with no success
this is the script in package.json "jest:clearCache": "jest --clearCache",
and in the pipeline now i run
npm i
npm run jest:clearCache
npm test
npm build
but npm test still fails, says
error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../Utils/TestUtils/RenderWithTheme' or its corresponding type declarations.

this wasn't an issue when the folder was called utils instead of Utils
RenderWithTheme is a react component.
Have also tried adding the following to my .d.ts just in case but its not that
declare module './Utils/TestUtils/RenderWithTheme'

Any ideas? I'm using go-server

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
